# Imread grayscale is different than imread + convert to grayscale

Tags: python, opencv

While working with OpenCV, I found a curious behavior and my knoledge couldn't explain it.
Maybe someone will have the answer.

```
image= cv.imread("image.jpg", 0)
__, thre = cv.threshold(image, 1, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(thre)
```

[image: result]

```
image = cv.imread("image.jpg")
image=  cv.cvtColor(output, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
__, thre = cv.threshold(image, 1, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY) 
plt.imshow(thre)
```

[image: result 2]

As you can see, the two images are a bit different.
Could someone explain me why using imread with flag 0 (grayscale) make a different result than using imread without a flag and convert it to grayscale after.

Is it because of the cvtColor flag ?

Comment: This does not answer you question but it is explained in the documentation : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56 When using IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, the codec's internal grayscale conversion will be used, if available. Results may differ to the output of cvtColor()

Comment: Are `image.jpg` and `output.jpg` the same images?

Comment: @AnnZen sorry, I made a typo, i edited. Yes there are the same.

Comment: @T.Lucas ok thank you this information, so it's better to use cvtColor() if we wants constant result ?

Comment: It depends on the reason you need the conversion from color to gray. The automatic conversion are mostly human-oriented in order to keep a similar contrast between the color image and the gray image. Without more information about what you are trying to achieve I cannot know which method is better, none probably. If you perform the conversion to simplify following image processing then make sure you can chose the conversion method by configuration and you will see later which one gives better result.

Comment: you chose a **threshold of 1**. that's next to black. you will make image artefacts visible like that. use a different threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is reason for effect you have observed, but I want to note that there exist two distinct ways of [RGB to Grayscale Conversion](https://mmuratarat.github.io/2020-05-13/rgb_to_grayscale_formulas): that is using mean and using weighted average, in later case different weights might be used, `cvtColor()` is said to use following formula

```
Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
```

there is also another formula provided in linked article with weights adjusted for human perception as follows

```
Z = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
```

Note that as above transformations are idempotent you might feed already grayscale image into them without care.

Comment: This is very interesting. I'm doing a lot of grayscale conversion in my project, and I never think about multiple ways to do it.
Since my project has to be pixel-perfect. Converting to grayscale from different languages, hardwares, and using differents libraries can be a source of error !
Would you recommend to define a formula for the whole project ? and doing it without lib ?

Comment: @Marie If you need *pixel-perfect* then why you use JPEG which is lossy?

Comment: Well the input images are in JPEG, so I guess the damage is already done. Right ? ^^